# Mocking __main__

Tags: python, mocking, unit-testing

I would like to ensure with tests that:
- the application cannot be imported
- the application can be started as a real application (i.e: python src.py)

I'm interested about that, why the following is not working:

src.py

```
class A:
 def x(self):
  print('this is x')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  A().x()
```

test.py (snippet)

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
  @mock.patch('src.A.x')
  def test_main(self, mock_x):
    import src
    mock_x.assert_any_call()
```

This test fails... why?

Answer (score 2):

Because the name of the module when imported is `src`, not `__main__`.

The easiest solution would be to move that code into a function:

```
def main():
    A().x()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and in your test, you would invoke `src.main()`

```
@mock.patch('src.A.x')
def test_main(self, mock_x):
    import src
    src.main()
    mock_x.assert_any_call()
```

Comment: that is not ensure that main() is called only when the application is called as a script (python src.py)

Comment: You are correct. You could also ensure that it is *not* called before calling `main()`

Answer (score 0):

To test that a module is not importable you do not need to use mocks.

See [`assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).

Just check if an error is thrown on import od module.

```
with self.assertRaises(...):
    ...
```

Comment: You said you want to ensure that your module can not be imported. This can be tested wit my code. Please be more precise in what you are asking and give sensefully comments rather than "that's not true... "...

Comment: If an module is not importable Python will raise an Error. That is what I guessed you wanted to test.

Comment: how do you ensure that, a module is not importable?!?!?!

Comment: Also...if you ensure it ... it doesn't say that the source is actually called in __main__...